# How can I use the constraints in native webrtc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, webrtc

I finally have an app that can make a connection with the other peer and both peers receive audio and video from the remote. It is an `iOS` app using the native `RTC` `API`. I am now trying out what I can do to improve the quality so I started looking for options in for the media constraints.

This is my initialization code:

```
//init
peerConnectionFactory = [[RTCPeerConnectionFactory alloc] init];
[RTCPeerConnectionFactory initializeSSL];

//set 2 arrays to be used for the media constraints
NSMutableArray *m = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *o = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//add stuff to the mandatory array
[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveAudio" value:@"true"]];
[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveVideo" value:@"true"]];

//add stuff to the optional array
//these lines are disabled for now, because my colleague working on the Android version does not support dtls yet
//[o addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"internalSctpDataChannels" value:@"true"]];
//[o addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement" value:@"true"]];

//use the 2 arrays to init the media constraints
constraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:m optionalConstraints:o];

//init stun and turn servers
RTCICEServer *turn = [[RTCICEServer alloc] initWithURI:[NSURL URLWithString:@"turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478"] username:@"*" password:@"*"];
RTCICEServer *stun = [[RTCICEServer alloc] initWithURI:[NSURL URLWithString:@"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"] username:@"" password:@""];
NSArray *iceServers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:turn, stun, nil];

//init the peerconnection object
peerConnection = [peerConnectionFactory peerConnectionWithICEServers:nil
                                                         constraints:constraints
                                                            delegate:self];
```

I tried to set the following RTCPairs:

First I tried these, just to see what it would do.

```
[o addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth" value:@"1280"]];
[o addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"720"]];
```

It did nothing.
Then I tried these lines (without the previous 2).

```
[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth" value:@"1280"]];
[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"720"]];
```

this causes the app to get stuck at generating ice candidates.
thinking the device might not support such high resolutions I tried the following.

```
[o addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"320"]];
[o addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"180"]];
```

no effect again.

I tried some more combinations I can't remember, but to me it seems like adding anything except `OfferToReceiveAudio` and `OfferToReceiveVideo` to the mandatory array just breaks the entire process and adding anything to the optional array is ignored (although setting the `dtls` thing makes it impossible to connect to the `Android` version).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was setting constraints for the peerconnection initialization, but they have to be set for the videosource. When creating the local media stream, you have to specify a camera, initialize a capturer with that camera, then set a videosource to use that capturer. When setting that video source, you can pass the constraints.